# What syntax and range information for the local AD attribute "msExchUsageLocation"?

Tags: windows, azure-active-directory, active-directory, exchange-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I would like to synchronize the `User Location` of a AD user between `local AD` and `Azure AD`.
I found out that the `local AD` attribute `msExchUsageLocation` will overgive the information to `User location` in `Azure AD`.

Due to we don't use any exchange service on my local Domain Controller there is no `AD attribute` called `msExchUsageLocation`. Means I have to create one specific local AD attribute first.

For creating the new attribute I need the Syntax and Range information. Do you know what I have to fill in there? Plus, do I have to activate the `Multi-Valued`?

Maybe someone of you have already this `local AD attribute` created, because you are usign exchange already.

[image]

Comment: You can find the information in the following link: 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-attributes-synchronized.md

Comment: @Aswin Thank you for your reply, unfortunately I was not able to find any info about msExchUsageLocation and my question / missing info about 'syntax info, min and max'.

Answer (score 0):

To add **msExchUsageLocation** correctly, you must extend your AD schema using the Microsoft Exchange AD prep tools. They're free to download and run in your environment. This is an important pre-requisite to syncing from your AD to Azure AD in Microsoft 365 and Exchange Online.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/prepare-ad-and-domains?view=exchserver-2019